# How can i log some information in the console with javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can i log some information in the console with javascript?

I tried `Debug.Log('Hello World')` but it didnt work.

Comment: try console.log('Hello World'), for more info kindly refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `console.log("Hello World")` :)